# Cannot Create SPRoleAssignment From User in Powershell

Tags: 2013, powershell, permissions

I have the following code:

```
foreach ($item in $head.GetItems()) {    
    $bigboss=$item['bigBoss'];
   $roleAssignment = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($bigboss);
}
```

Where $head is a SPList, and "bigBoss" is of Type "Person or Group" (which should be of type SPPrincipal)

$bigBoss is not null (has a value like "1;#Chef")

When trying to set the roleAssignment I get the following error:

```
New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "SPRoleAssignment" and the argument
count: "1".
At C:\dev\whatever\modifyperm.ps1:58 char:31
+             $roleAssignment = New-Object
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($ ...
+
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodExcept
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.Power
   Shell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out by myself. 
$item["BigBoss"] did not return the SPUser-Object

So I had to cast that using the following code:

```
foreach ($item in $head.GetItems()) {    
    $bigbossItem=$item['bigBoss'];
    $bigBossObj=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue($web, $bigbossItem) 
    $bigBoss=$bigBossObj.User


   $roleAssignment = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($bigboss); }
```